# jQuery - How do I assign data-values to an option based on the value of another option?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'm looking to write a snippet of jQuery based on variables, but I'm not sure the best way to go around this.

I have two select fields, the first one has options with values and the second one has options with data-values. depending on what option/value is selected in the first select field, I need to dynamically update the data-value in the option of the second field.

My HTML is:

```
<select required="" name="options" id="cab" class="select-model">
    <option selected="" data-value="0" disabled="disabled"></option>
    <option data-value="500" value="1" class="one">1x12 Cabinet</option>
    <option data-value="1000" value="2">2x12 Cabinet</option>
    <option data-value="1500" value="3">3x15 Cabinet</option>
    <option data-value="0" value="0">No cabinet</option>
</select>

<select required="" name="options" id="speaker" class="select-model">
    <option selected="" data-value="0" disabled="disabled"></option>
    <option data-value="0">Celestion</option>
    <option data-value="100" class="widow">Black Widow</option>
</select>

<var class="total">0</var>
```

And my current jQuery snippet is:

```
$("#cab").on('change', function () { 
    $("#cab").prop($(this).val() == "1x12 Cabinet");
    $(".widow").attr('data-value', 100);        
});
```

This works fine but I need to assign a variable so that the data-value for the Black Widow is:

- multiplied by 2 (or set to 200) when value=2 is selected in #cab
- multiplied by 3 (or set to 300) when value=3 is selected in #cab

etc...

I have tried creating a var map already but I'm afraid my jQuery isn't good enough yet!

[Here's a link to a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liamtarpey/aKkej/4/)

Comment: Isn't `$("#cab").prop($(this).val() == "1x12 Cabinet");` a long and inefficient way of doing nothing? Did you intend to _set_ some property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#cab").on('change', function () { 
    var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $(".widow").attr('data-value', value * 100);
});
```

Hope this help! updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/aKkej/5/

Comment: Absolutely exactly what I was looking for. Sorry if I made the question a bit tricky, found this very hard to explain. Thanks again!

Comment: also you can use $(".widow").data("value") = value *100;
inspite of $(".widow").attr('data-value', value * 100);